# java - check table existence in sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

is there a way to check if the table is already existed. It always prompt me t

[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table player_record already exist).

this is what i want to do

```
if(player_record is existing){
  don't create table;
}else{
  create table;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For my project, I created a method that looks like this. Instead of doing a query it uses the database's metadata.

```
    public boolean tableExists(String tableName){
        connect();
        try{
            DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, tableName, null);
            rs.last();
             return rs.getRow() > 0;
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(SQLite.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here is a class that goes along with it:

```
public class SQL{

    protected Connection conn = null;
    protected String dbName = "mydatabase.db";

    public void connect(){
        if(conn != null){
            return;
        }
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbName);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public boolean tableExists(String tableName){
        connect();
        try{
            DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, tableName, null);
            rs.last();
            return rs.getRow() > 0;
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(SQLite.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I then use it like this:

```
SQL sql = new SQL();
if(sql.tableExists("myTableName")){
    // Table Exists!
}else{
    // Table doesn't exist.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To find table exist or not using query is

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name';
```

Execute this and then check name is null or not

Answer (score 2):

SQLite's [CREATE TABLE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) has the IF NOT EXISTS clause:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player_record (
    [...]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS - did not work for me.
Also statement for sqlite_master had error if table do not exist, so try catch block solve problem:

```
try {
String tableExists = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name';";        
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet ex = statement.executeQuery(tableExists);
String exS = ex.getString(1);       
System.out.println("Table " + exS + " exists.");        
}catch (SQLException e){
System.out.println("Table NOT exists.");        
}
```

Comment: why create table if not exists didn't work for you?

Comment: I do not know. There was some error in both cases (table exists and do not exists). So i push forward and found this solution which is ok.

Comment: Just to emphasise, I am programming in Eclipse, making JavaFX app which communicates with SQLite DB.